# Exception: Invalid image data

Tags: flutter

This is my app:

[image: enter image description]

I want to get the image in the circle but I'm not getting the image:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final imageUrl ="https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.licdn.com%2Fdms%2Fimage%2FD4E03AQHQw81O6YMl0g%2Fprofile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200%2F0%2F1689344752868%3Fe%3D2147483647%26v%3Dbeta%26t%3DeXZBbFDnXIU3-Mo0nTT539nyi7w0eHA9EYl8P1rW_cs&tbnid=mMbVxxezSlgR6M&vet=12ahUKEwj7nPnZ0LKEAxXbS2wGHTURBHkQMygAegQIARBI..i&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fin.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Fsaumya-sura-a73734270&docid=3yOB7YRgEd_KcM&w=200&h=200&q=saumya%20sura&ved=2ahUKEwj7nPnZ0LKEAxXbS2wGHTURBHkQMygAegQIARBI";
    return Drawer(
      child:Container(
        color:Colors.deepPurple ,
```

Comment: Probably because that Google image needs auth. I assume it's not public.

Comment: That link points to a web page, not an image. https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/D4E03AQHQw81O6YMl0g/profile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200/0/1689344752868?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=eXZBbFDnXIU3-Mo0nTT539nyi7w0eHA9EYl8P1rW_cs would be an image

Comment: you URL is not an image.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @tevemadar's comment. Please use the provided [URL](https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/D4E03AQHQw81O6YMl0g/profile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200/0/1689344752868?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=eXZBbFDnXIU3-Mo0nTT539nyi7w0eHA9EYl8P1rW_cs) instead of the one you've used in your code, as the URL you've used does not link to an image.